# Retract of a simply connected space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

I'm trying to really understand retractions and the fundamental group, and I came across this corollary that stumped me in trying to prove:

> $\textbf{Corollary:}$ A retract of a simply connected space is simply connected.

Now, what I know about retractions is that if A is a retract of X, then I have a retraction map
\begin{equation}r:X\rightarrow A\end{equation}
And the homomorphism induced by it,
\begin{equation} \iota_{A*}:\pi_1(A,p)\rightarrow \pi_1(X,p)\end{equation}
For any $p\in A$ is injective.

I have a simply connected space, so it's fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$ is trivial. I want to show that $\pi_1(A)$ is also trivial. So, examine what happens in the above induced mapping.....

And this is where I can't figure out how to finish the proof. Can someone explain to me how the injectivity of $\iota_{A*}$ makes $\pi_1(A,p)$ trivial? I feel like it's something really easy but I am not quite seeing it.

I really want to say that $\iota_{A*}$ is also surjective. Why can I not say that? Or can I?

Thanks!

Comment: You have an injective homomorphism from the group $\pi_1(A,p)$ to the trivial group but any homomorphism to the trivial group is surjective so it's an isomorphism.

Comment: Suppose $f\colon H \to G$ is a map of sets. Suppose $G$ has only one element $*$: every element of $H$  must map to $*$. On the other hand if $f$ is injective, then the cardinality of $f^{-1}(*)$ is at most $1$. Since all $H$ maps  to $*$, $H$ has cardinality $1$.

Comment: Ok that clarifies my thinking. I should have been thinking of the map as taking path classes to path classes. So since our range has only 1 element and we have an injective function, we must have only 1 element in our domain. I knew it was something simple :)

Comment: been there, done that....